# "Treats" here means

Tags: articles

Is "treats" here only means food? or "treats" is the food that is offered by a host when you are a guest?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/treat, a treat can just be a food you eat for pleasure, like christmas cookies or sweets.

So it does not just mean food, the article is referring to christmas food which is not particularly healthy.